# How do I solve: pandoc: ...:hGetContents: invalid argument (invalid byte sequence)

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, pandoc

I'm running the following code in terminal on Mac OSX 10.6.8:

`find . -name \*.html -type f -exec pandoc -o {}.md {} \;`

It parses some documents, but gives me this error on quite a few:

`pandoc: ./Teaching/how_16825_make-lesson-book.html: hGetContents: invalid argument (invalid byte sequence)`

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

Having the same problem I also see this is in the Pandoc README.html file:---

> Pandoc uses the UTF-8 character encoding for both input and output. If your local character
> encoding is not UTF-8, you should pipe input and output through iconv:
>
> iconv -t utf-8 input.txt | pandoc | iconv -f utf-8

Of course you may need iconv instqalled first (Mac Osx already has it I beleive) ...

> http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/libiconv.htm Gnu Win32
>
> https://code.google.com/p/win-iconv/  Google Win-Iconv

Answer (score 2):

As kadeix said, this is a character encoding issue. Modifying the charset declaration in the html didn't do anything for me.

In vim to solve this issue I used: `:w ++enc=utf-8`

Answer (score 0):

I get this error when i try to parse a file encoded in latin-1.

Try saving the file in utf-8 (and modify the charset declaration in the html code) before using pandoc when you get this error.